# SQL Server CTE average with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I've been trying to visualise how to do this with a CTE as it appears on the surface to be the best way but just can't get it going. Maybe it needs a temp table as well. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I need to create intercepts (a length along a line essentially) with the following parameters.

1. The average of the intercept must be greater than .7
2. The aim is to get the largest intercept possible
3. There can be up to 2 consecutive meters of values less than .7 (internal waste) but no more
4. There is no limit to the total internal waste within an intercept
5. There is no minimum intercept length (well there is but I'll take care of it later)

Note: there will be no gaps as I has taken care of that and the from and to can be decimal

An example is shown here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68fHs.jpg)

In space seen here with the assay on the left and depth on right:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDLUl.jpg)

So for a little more clarity if needed, intervals 6 to 7 and 17 to 18 do not make part of the larger intercept as the internal waste (7-9 and/or 15-17) would bring the average below 0.7 - not because of the amount of internal waste.

However the result for 21-22 is not included because there are 3 meters of internal waste between it and the result for 17-18.

Note that there are multiple sites and areas which make part of the original tables primary key so I imagine that a partition of area and site would be used in any ROW_NUMBER OVER statements

Edit: the original code had errors in the from and to (multiple 14 to 15) which would have been confusing sorry.  There will be no overlapping from-to's which hopefully simplifies things.

Example values to use:

```
create table #temp_inter (
area nvarchar(10),
site_ID nvarchar(10),
d_from decimal (18,3),
d_to decimal (18,3),
assay decimal (18,3))

insert into #temp_inter
values ('area_1','abc','0','5','0'),
('area_1','abc','5','6','0.165'),
('area_1','abc','6','7','0.761'),
('area_1','abc','7','8','0.321'),
('area_1','abc','8','9','0.292'),
('area_1','abc','9','10','1.135'),
('area_1','abc','10','11','0.225'),
('area_1','abc','11','12','0.983'),
('area_1','abc','12','13','0.118'),
('area_1','abc','13','14','0.438'),
('area_1','abc','14','15','0.71'),
('area_1','abc','15','16','0.65'),
('area_1','abc','16','17','2'),
('area_1','abc','17','18','0.367'),
('area_1','abc','18','19','0.047'),
('area_1','abc','19','20','0.71'),
('area_1','abc','20','21','0'),
('area_1','abc','21','22','0'),
('area_1','abc','22','23','0'),
('area_1','abc','23','24','2'),
('area_1','abc','24','25','0'),
('area_1','abc','25','26','0'),
('area_1','abc','26','30','0'),
('area_2','zzz','0','5','0'),
('area_2','zzz','5','6','1.165'),
('area_2','zzz','6','7','0.396'),
('area_2','zzz','7','8','0.46'),
('area_2','zzz','8','9','0.111'),
('area_2','zzz','9','10','0.053'),
('area_2','zzz','10','11','0.057'),
('area_2','zzz','11','12','0.055'),
('area_2','zzz','12','13','0.03'),
('area_2','zzz','13','14','0.026'),
('area_2','zzz','14','15','0.194'),
('area_2','zzz','15','16','0.367'),
('area_2','zzz','16','17','0.431'),
('area_2','zzz','17','18','0.341'),
('area_2','zzz','18','19','0.071'),
('area_2','zzz','19','20','0.26'),
('area_2','zzz','20','21','0.659'),
('area_2','zzz','21','22','0.602'),
('area_2','zzz','22','23','2.436'),
('area_2','zzz','23','24','0.874'),
('area_2','zzz','24','25','3.173'),
('area_2','zzz','25','26','0.179'),
('area_2','zzz','26','27','0.065'),
('area_2','zzz','27','28','0.024'),
('area_2','zzz','28','29','0')
```

Comment: This looks like a problem that would be easier to solve with a application language.  Rule sets like this just don't lend themselves to sql.  Would be easy in C# using linq and Aggregate() function..

Comment: This problem seems to have multiple constrainsts that have to be optimized. It might still be possible with pure SQL but it's gonna be hit & miss for anyone trying to help you. Your question is so domain specific that you really need to explain the context of the problem in sufficient detail. I have no idea in what context you are using terms like interval, internal waste, meters, or how the picture you posted relates to the rest. I get you didn't want to write an essay here, but it's just not enough to go on.

Comment: Thanks peoples.  @robertdeniro the context is that of drilling for minerals (mining industry).   Hopefully the extra image clarifies it somewhat but in addition an interval is the length an assay represents.  This is always in meters but doesn't have to be an integer. Imagine putting a straw into a layered cake and taking out the top 1cm - that is your first interval/assay then going back in the same hole and getting the next 1cm and so on.  What I want is to find what parts of the cake are on average more than 0.7% chocolate but some other layers (less than 0.7) can be in the calculation.

Comment: Also @robertdeniro the original image and example code had multiple intervals for meters 14 to 15 which was wrong and would have added to the complexity.  For a give site(drill hole) there will be no overlapping intervals and no gaps.

Comment: @famethrowa Why you do not include 22-23 interval with 23-24, the average will be 1 in this case?

Comment: Good question. While one goal is to create the largest intercept the other is to obtain the highest average assay grade. As such waste should not be included unless it's acting as a bridge to another assay above the cut-off grade(0.7) or else you are diluting the average grade.

Comment: The biggest issue is how to get average by unknown boundary. We can calculate average amount by month or by year. It has to have starting and end points. But it is missing in your case. You may have to artificially define all the possible boundaries, then able to get all averages.

Comment: You have counted intervals 9-16 as having an average assay of 0.782. If the aim is to maximize the length of the intercept, why is interval 8 with an assay of 0.292 not included in this intercept? It would make the interval 1m longer, and the average assay would still be 0.728, which is above your threshold of 0.7. If the goal is to maximize average assay over length, then why is interval 9 with 1.135 not on it's own? In fact if the goal is to maximize average assay over length, the problem would reduce to selecting individual intervals greater than 0.7

Comment: Sorry for the delay – have been away.  @robertdeniro it’s a bit hard to explain as it is an industry specific concept but the goal is an interplay between grade(or average) and length but with rules.  As I stated in an earlier comment – waste(<0.7) should not be included unless it's acting as a bridge to another assay above the cut-off grade(0.7) or else you are diluting the average grade which is not acceptable in the industry.

Comment: In a nutshell the first and last assay of an intercept must be >= the cut-off grade (0.7 in this case) and the average of the intercept must also be >= the cut-off grade.  With this in mind @Wendy while the boundaries are unknown to begin with, we do have a finite amount of possibilities due to defined boundary parameters.

Comment: The logic needed as I see it is roughly this using site abc:
1. Starting at the beginning of the given range (ie 0) find the first assay >= 0.7.  Interval 6-7.
2. Progressing down the sequence, find the next assay that is above 0.7 where there has not been more than two consecutive metres of assays less than 0.7. Interval 19-20.
3. Now the range 6-20 meets criteria 1 for the start/end of range being  >=0.7 and having not more than 2 metres consecutive internal waste(<0.7) criteria 2.

Comment: 4. This range now needs to be averaged and if it is >= 0.7 it is flagged as a valid intercept.  If not we know that criteria 2 is still going to be met so we need to shorten the interval but meet criteria 1 again.  Should this result in two new intercepts of the same length with a, the highest average grade of the two would be taken. If the average any shortened range still does not reach 0.7, then step 4 would be repeated until a valid intercept is attained.

Comment: Note also that intercepts cannot overlap i.e. for site abc, the interval 16 to 17 cannot be included in an intercept for both 9-17 and 16 to 20.